# Scaffold-DbContext Stored Procedures only in EF Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

I have always used code-first with EF Core, Now I need to use Database-First. There are lots of questions, documents, and tutorials about this, teaching how to [scaffold a database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-dbcontext-scaffold),

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models
```

However, my only requirement here is missing in all of them. I need to scaffold only a few stored procedures and views, but all these documents and question say is about how to include tables.

I was going to scaffold including everything and then delete unwanted ones manually, but it doesn't seem to be the right choice.

Comment: Many database-first workflows are not completely automated.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft yeah I got that, but is there a way to include stored procedures and views even manually?

Comment: If you just need the stored procedures and views, I'd say create an empty migration and add the SP's and views manually.

Comment: @Dennis1679 do you have any examples?

Comment: Sure, I will answer with an example if you like.

Comment: @Dennis1679 thanks a lot, please include a view and a stored procedure

Comment: The logic will be the same for both. I'll create an example for you.

Comment: maybe this works for you? `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("YourStoredProcedure @p0, @p1", parameters: new[] { "Joseph", "Gates" });`

Comment: @StepUp yes, but what about views? `Scaffold-DbContext` has `-t` switch for including tables, but i tried it does now work for views

Comment: I will try to do like this `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Select Id, Name from myView");`

Comment: I would try to execute views and SP without scaffolding. In my view, it is perfectly fine.

Comment: @StepUp it seems that I'm gonna go the way you said. let me also try ErikEJ answer

Comment: @StepUp I suggest that you add both your comments as an answer, as they are the only way that works for both stored procedure and views

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to call a raw SQL using `ExecuteSqlCommand`. So code to call stored procedure would be look like that:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("YourStoredProcedure @p0, @p1", 
    parameters: new[] { "Joseph", "Gates" });
```

**UPDATE:**

[As msdn says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) about how to get rows from stored procedures:

> Raw SQL queries can be used to execute a stored procedure.

```
var user = "johndoe";

var blogs = context.Blogs
    .FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE dbo.GetMostPopularBlogsForUser {0}", user)
    .ToList();
```

> The following example uses a raw SQL query that selects from a
>   Table-Valued Function (TVF), then disables change tracking with the
>   call to AsNoTracking:

```
var searchTerm = ".NET";

var blogs = context.Blogs
    .FromSqlInterpolated($"SELECT * FROM dbo.SearchBlogs({searchTerm})")
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This does not return any results

Answer (score 5):

Use EF Core Power Tools, it allows you to select what to scaffold, and saves your selection.

Comment: Oh its a really great tool, it is only missing the stored procedures.

Comment: How would reverse engineered of stored procedures look in code?

Comment: Provide a reference to query against, with parameters listed would be awesome.

Comment: Indeed, it scaffolds stored procedures, even with sp returning with multiple result sets

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone landed here looking to execute stored procedure in MySQL database from EntityFramework Core, the following code should work.

```
var blogTagId = 1;
var tags = await _dbContext.BlogTags.FromSqlRaw("CALL SP_GetBlogTags({0})", blogTagId).ToListAsync();
```